# Java date parsing issue - SimpleDateFormat automatically decrements month

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I try to parse Date from String with pattern:

```
final static String DATE_RU_PATTERN = "dd.MM.yyyy"; 
private static SimpleDateFormat ruFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_RU_PATTERN);
public static Date GetDateFromStringRuFormat (String dateString){       
    try {       
        return ruFormatter.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Why ruFormatter.parse(dateString) gives Date with decremented values of Month?

```
@Test
public void TestGetDateFromStringRuFormat(){
    final String dateString = "24.09.2015";
    Calendar actualCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date actualResult = DateFormatHelper.GetDateFromStringRuFormat(dateString);
    actualCalendar.setTime(actualResult);
    assertEquals(9, actualCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)); // FAILS 
    assertEquals(24, actualCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    assertEquals(2015, actualCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Calendar` like `java.util.Date` starts counting months from 0. 
So whenever you want to do something meaningful with the month value, add 1 to it.

From the [Javadoc](http://file:///E:/static/java/docs8/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH):

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a
>   calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian
>   and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the
>   number of months in a year.

Therfore your unit test should read:

```
assertEquals(9, actualCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Months in the Calendar class start at zero:

```
JANUARY = 0
FEBRUARY = 1
```

...

So September = 8 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH).

Try changing your test to:

```
assertEquals(Calendar.SEPTEMBER, actualCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```